# Subtracting a string converted to an int then back to string:

Tags: c#, asp.net, time

Here is my code.  I cannot figure out why it isn't working. It is telling me to write more down.

```
int todayINTyear = 0;
    int birthINTyear = 0;
    int antINTyear = 0;

    DOB_whole.Value = DayDOB_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + MonthDOB_DLL.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + YearDOB_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
    todayYear_Value.Value = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    todayINTyear = Int32.Parse(yearValue.Value.ToString());
    birthINTyear = Int32.Parse(YearDOB_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
    antINTyear = Int32.Parse(AGE.Value.ToString());

    antINTyear = birthINTyear - todayINTyear;

    string AGE_Value = antINTyear.ToString();

    AGE_Displayed.Value = AGE_Value;

    AGELabel.Text = AGE_Displayed.Value.ToString();
```

Line that's bad:

> todayINTyear = Int32.Parse(yearValue.Value.ToString());

Stack Trace

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>      System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14502124
>      System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +172
>      Registration.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\motorcity3d.com\www\Registration.aspx.cs:145
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785

Comment: what is yearValue here? does it contains any string with characters?

Comment: It's just a hiddenfield...empty I imagine.

Comment: you are trying to convert empty value to int. this is not right. you must pass some string than can be converted to int. for Example "2"

Comment: I had a misspelling.  But now birthINTyear is throwing it.

Comment: What *is* that value that doesn't parse? A null maybe?

Comment: It's the year from a dropdownlist.  It has a value because the function about it is stored int he DB.

Comment: the exception is pretty clear, *Input string was not in a correct format*. For a string to be parseable, it must contain at least one digit, it must only contain digits, and it may optionally have a leading sign (+/-). Anything else throws. Evaluate your values and/or check how they are created ...

Comment: From the exception, it seems, this happens on PageLoad. Are you sure, the dropdown is already populated and a value is selected? Maybe you have a default like "select year" or something like that.

Comment: They are.  They are posting to the DB.  I edited my code above showing the function above this code.

Comment: There is "Day", "Month", "Year" in the dropdowns.

Comment: Well, obviously, if an exception is thrown, the selected value in the dropdown is not parseable to int. Add a breakpoint and check what the value is.

Comment: I can't do it...my database is not local and it is already connected.

Comment: I found it.  It was a value that was Null.  Thanks guys.